# HTTP status code 304 when using Cloudflare

Tags: http, web, caching, networking, cloudflare

Is it usefull to set the HTTP status code to 304 on the webserver when using the caching of Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should respond with a 304 in the same cases you would normally: when an `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` header is present and the condition isn't satisfied, and hence the client's copy is still fresh.

Cloudflare may forward such requests from the user's browser (if Cloudflare couldn't satisfy the request from its own cache). Additionally, Cloudflare may generate such requests itself in order to revalidate the content in its own cache. It's better to send the 304 response than to re-send the same content, in order to save server-side bandwidth and get the content to the end user more quickly.